# Sort series on index for the values that are equal

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, series

I have a Pandas series here:

> s1=pd.Series([23,23,21,21,25,25,25])

Now when i do s1.value_counts(), i get another series which is this image:

[image]

What i want to do is, get the indexes with duplicate values, sort them based on index and place them back to the series. In this case, the output would be:

[image]

I have tried putting it in a dictionary, flipping the values and then sorting the values. But is there a much more pandas efficient way to do this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the result of this what you want: `s1.value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False)`?

Comment: Hey, No. I only want to sort the indexes whose values are equal. The rest order of the series stays the same

Comment: I dont really understand how you want to sort, because if it is based on index, the first image is correct because 23 is the 0th index and comes first before 21?

Comment: 23 is the index in that case. So 23 is the index and 2 is the value and its above 21. 23 and 21 both have the same values. So i need to sort them based on their index. Basically want 21 first and then 23

Comment: Exactly. But for the indexes with same value, i want to sort in ascending without disturbing the order of the rest of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this is what you are after?:

```
import pandas as pd
s1=pd.Series([23,23,21,21,25,25,25])
s1.value_counts().sort_index(ascending=True).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Comment: No. i want to sort based on index only when the values are equal

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about "without disturbing the order of the rest of the list". Docs say that `value_counts` sorts from most common to least common, so you can recreate this order and sort indexes within each group. You can do it by treating index as another column and then sorting on two columns - counts and index. Like this

```
s1.value_counts().reset_index().\
  sort_values([0,'index'],ascending=[False,True]).\
  set_index('index')`
```